# MAX IF over column not recognizing values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make an excel formula which will find the maximum value in a range of a column (P) where adjacent value in Q is equal to 2 minus value adjacent to the  cell with the formula. For example, if I had

```
 p | q | r
 2 | 4 | formula
 3 | 6 | formula
 4 | 8 | formula
 5 | 8 | formula
 6 | 10| formula
```

I would want the formula to make it

```
 p | q | r
 2 | 4 | 0
 3 | 6 | 2
 4 | 8 | 3
 5 | 8 | 3
 6 | 10| 4
```

Currently I have

```
=MAX(IF(Q:Q=(Q5-2),P$2:P5))
```

The numbers in Q are generated using the formula below, which counts the number of spaces in cells in a different column and is working as intended.

```
=FIND(LEFT(TRIM(A5),1),A5)-1
```

Comment: which version of excel are you using?

Comment: @girlvsdata excel 2011 on mac. The file in question is a CSV, if it is relevant

Comment: what is your formula in Col R currently returning?

Comment: @girlvsdata column R is returning 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you've given is an array, it needs to be closed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Column Q's range also needs to be the same size as Column P's.

Put this in R2 and instead of ENTER, press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to run the formula. When it works the formula will be enclosed in curly brackets.

```
=MAX(IF($Q$2:$Q$6=(Q2-2),$P$2:$P$6))
```

Comment: I only want to find the maximum values for the rows above the cell with formula. That is why I limited it in the original formula.

Comment: OK, then you just need to make sure both ranges are the same size. I'll update my answer.

Comment: No worries, happy to help!